# Error while debugging NodeJs program using mocha

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, node-debugger

I have written some test cases and I am trying to debug the test cases using using mocha and node debug.

I have mocha installed on my machine

I installed node-debug     `npm install -g node-debug`

Then I am running test by this command: `node-debug _mocha test.js`

This opens a browser window, but I am getting following error

```
Detached from the target

Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED. Is node running with --debug port 5858?
Please re-attach to the new target.
```

See the attached image for more information:

[image]

How can I get rid of this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior once your tests have finished running.  Put a long timeout in your test so it does not die and try it again.

You will also want to run mocha with a very high timeout so your tests don't die timing out.

Comment: How do we `run mocha with a very high timeout`. How can I put ` long timeout in test`

Comment: on the command line you can specify --timeout 15000 to specify 15 seconds for all tests.  otw you can also put this in each test to have a different timeout per test.

Comment: or --no-timeouts

Answer (score 0):

The `node-debug` project is deprecated.

If using node > 6.3, The debugger is a part of the node core!

see https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.3qx9qfmwl

If using node < 6.3, you can use node-inspector

Check out https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

The rest should be smooth sailing if your test is not ending the process before you're done debugging. You can also set `--debug-brk` so it stops on the first line of your code to give us slow humans a chance to get to the debuggeer.

Best of luck!